Retrieve all Mapillary images which show a feature with a particular id
On Mapillary website, users can observe the location of features detected by Mapillary. For example, we can look at utility poles in Eastern Finland:

If I click on the image on the left, I can view the images in full, not just the thumbnail:

I would like to programmatically obtain the URLs for images with detected point features (I am primarily interested in utility poles, but not filtering for them is fine for now) within a webmercator tile.
I can get information on featues within a tile. Let's take 14/9523/4629 tile (boundaries via this). There are 7 detected features within this tile:

(Tile boundaries are approximate, I draw them manually.)
To get these features, I do:
curl 'https://tiles.mapillary.com/maps/vtp/mly_map_feature_point/2/14/9523/4629?access_token=MAPILLARY_TOKEN' \
  --output tile.pbf

ogr2ogr tile.geojson tile.pbf

tile.geojson is:
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "point",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "mvt_id": 0, "first_seen_at": 1532260308499, "id": 325920865600258, "last_seen_at": 1532260308499, "value": "object--support--utility-pole" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2787.0, 4029.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "mvt_id": 1, "first_seen_at": 1531416074000, "id": 149073303804394, "last_seen_at": 1531416074000, "value": "object--support--utility-pole" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1727.0, 3005.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "mvt_id": 2, "first_seen_at": 1531416077000, "id": 226858372167178, "last_seen_at": 1531416077000, "value": "object--support--utility-pole" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1438.0, 2748.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "mvt_id": 3, "first_seen_at": 1532260318322, "id": 325935775598767, "last_seen_at": 1532260318322, "value": "object--support--utility-pole" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2291.0, 3504.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "mvt_id": 4, "first_seen_at": 1565459236000, "id": 304588334603788, "last_seen_at": 1565459236000, "value": "object--support--utility-pole" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 293.0, 1816.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "mvt_id": 5, "first_seen_at": 1565459243000, "id": 304608991268389, "last_seen_at": 1565459243000, "value": "object--support--utility-pole" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 758.0, 2190.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "mvt_id": 6, "first_seen_at": 1532260313989, "id": 326047465587598, "last_seen_at": 1532260313989, "value": "object--support--utility-pole" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2410.0, 3596.0 ] } }
]
}

Reassuringly, I have 7 features in this GeoJSON, and 7 features visible on the Mapillary website within 14/9523/4629 . However, this is where I am stuck: I don't know how to retrieve the images on which I can observe these features. Each feature has an id, which is probably essential to proceed.
How can I retrieve all Mapillary images which show a feature with a particular id?

its using graphql?doc=query to retrieve the images but only mapillary.com is allowed access/domain controlled example mapillary.com https://graph.mapillary.com/graphql? with doc id will get you a 190 error 'Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token' this would out of scope on GIS SE

The website is using the graphql endpoint, but there might be a more accessible option. Do you see a way to bring this question within scope?
